# Foreach problem in c#

Tags: c#, winforms, foreach

i try to make a foreach loop in c#. In textbox1 is the location and now i will try to list all folders in textbox2. But i don't find the error:

```
        string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(@"" + textBox1.Text + "");
        foreach (string value in filePaths)
        {
            textBox2.Text = "" + value + "\n";
        }
```

I hope someone can help me.

Regards

Comment: To insert a new line in a TextBox, first make sure you have the MultiLine property of the TextBox set to True. Then use \r\n (carriage return and new line), as in the following example: TextBox1.Text = "First line\r\nSecond line";

Comment: You might want to investigate using a `ListBox` or a `ListView`, rather than a multi-line `TextBox`. That's a much more natural control for what you're trying to display, and it saves you the trouble of doing all that string concatenation. (Also, why are you "terminating" strings with a `""`? There's no reason to do that. You aren't adding a space, and neither is that a null terminator nor do you need to null-terminate C# strings yourself.)

Comment: Pro-tip: name your controls. You don't want waste your time figuring out if the person name is in textBox23 or textBox17.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're resetting the `Text` property on each iteration. At the minimum, use `+=` instead of `=`. If you're working with a large number of strings, it will be worth learning about the `StringBuilder` class for efficient string concatenation operations, particularly those happening inside loops.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
foreach (string path in filePaths)
{
    sb.AppendLine(path);
}
textBox2.Text = sb.ToString();
```

Answer (score 5):

I fixed it for you.

```
    string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(textBox1.Text);
    foreach (string value in filePaths)
    {
        textBox2.Text += value + Environment.NewLine;
    }
```

You were using = instead of += which meant the textBox2.Text only had the last file name in the list instead of all of the files.

I also got rid of some pointless "" you added and changed "\n" into Environment.NewLine.

Comment: You forgot to change `+=` to a `StringBuilder`. Almost guaranteed to be enough files in a directory to make it worth your while.

Comment: Yea but I figured we'd cover one problem at a time ;)